# Opening a Google Authentication window in swing application on button click

Tags: java, swing

I am coding a java swing application where I need to connect with Google Analytic s API, for which the application will ask for credentials and connect internally.

I need to know if there is a way to log in using the Google Authentication window in swing application. Basically,  when the person clicks on log in button, I want to open Google Authentication window and on successful I want to come back to the application.

May be I am missing the exact terms, please guide me if there is a way to achieve this.

Comment: Why do you need the Google Authentication window? Can't you let user enter login password and send them to google to do the authentication?

Comment: due to the security reasons, don't want the user to enter the credentials directly, for which I need to provide the authentication window..